# How can I filter my array by elements that are present in another array

Tags: php, controller, twig, symfony4, array-difference

I need to filter my array by elements that are present in another array.

More in details, I have two variables (arrays) in my Controller: one contains ALL users, another - users that are participated in evaluation. What I need is the third variable/or the list in twig (array) that will contain ALL THE REST - so I can choose from them out of a dropdown list for every evaluation (names that are already in evaluation won't appear in the dropdown list).

I am wondering now what is the best approach to do this.. Should I do this in twig or in controller?

Thank you!

twig:

```
<select name="user" >
   {% for user in users %}
      <option value="{{ user.idUser }}" label="{{ user.name }} ">  
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

controller:

```
    $evals = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(User::class)
        ->findUserGroups();             // this is my own function (based on SQL query) from repository that searches for those who participated in evaluation

    $users = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(User::class)
        ->findAll();                    //this is a variable that contains ALL users (including those who already participated in evaluation)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This would be best handled in a controller, and you can use php's `array_diff` to do it.

controller:

```
$evals = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(User::class)
    ->findUserGroups();

$users = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(User::class)
    ->findAll();

$non_evals = array_diff($users, $evals);
```

then in twig:

```
<select name="user" >
   {% for user in non_evals %}
      <option value="{{ user.idUser }}" label="{{ user.name }} ">  
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you ehymel! However when I try to dump my $non_evals - I've got an error Object of class App\Entity\User could not be converted to string... Can you please explain what is it about? Thank you again

Comment: The easiest way to handle is to create a `__toString()` funciton in your User entity. See the docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php.

Comment: Though I have no symfony experience, I do NOT trust this answer because `array_diff()` DEFINITELY does not work with multidimensional structures.